# Share send byte[] buffer among multiple SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, socketasynceventargs

In a scenario where I always send the same data to many clients, i.e. in a scenario where I should (and in the future will) probably switch to using (e.g. PGM) multicast, **would it be thread-safe** to use the the same `byte[]` array instance on multiple `SocketAsyncEventArgs` and hand them to multiple sockets via `SendAsync` to be sent **concurrently**?

After all, SendAsync should *only read* from the buffer, so sharing the instance shouldn't be an issue. I guess to enable reuse of that buffer afterwards, I' d have to do reference counting and there may be other issues to tackle, but my question is first and foremost about thread safety.